# Error inflating View

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I got an error when trying to run my app with Android studio.
I tried to change the Image and It run normally but when I put my image it won't run.

This the image that made the error:

[image]

This is my code layout :

This is my activity:

```
public class AppActivity extends ActivityBase {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app);         
    }
}
```

and this is the error I get:

```
  AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.ifsoft.qachat/ru.ifsoft.qachat.AppActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                      at ru.ifsoft.qachat.AppActivity.onCreate(AppActivity.java:39)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020426 a=-1 r=0x7f020426}
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1960)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
                      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1021)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1080)
                      at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:668)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                      at ru.ifsoft.qachat.AppActivity.onCreate(AppActivity.java:39) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Comment: is logo.png in your drawable folder?

Comment: also check the name of your image file if it matches with the one you are using in ImageView

Comment: yes, it is in my drawable and it appears normally in android studio layout preview

Comment: but when running the app, the app through that error.

Comment: post your activity code as well.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: This should work. Can you upload the logo.png as well? I will try to run it in my device

Comment: **<RelativeLayout>android:visibility="gone"</RelativeLayout>** where **ImageView** is inside a container whose **parent's visibility** is basically set to **gone**?? How can you expect ImageView to show when it's parent container is not visible(forget visibility, **android:visibility="gone"** even removes the space spawned by the **view**)

Comment: I uploaded it to the question

Comment: I changed the visibility but the error still appear.

Comment: It works for me. Show me a screenshot of where your image is placed. Is it in drawable or some specific folder drawable-hdpi

Comment: it is in drawable-hdpi

Comment: I have added an answer with explanation and an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You device is not hdpi so when android runs it it looks for the image in respective folder and crashes because it can't find it. You can either

1. Put the image in all drawable folders ldpi, hdpi, xhdpi, mdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi .
2. Or, you can put it only in the "drawable" folder

   [image: folder structure]